# How to identify that a user changed subscription in manage->setting?

Tags: ios, storekit

We support subscriptions in our apps and now users can change the subscription from the settings->manage subscriptions button on their ios devices.

How can we find out about these kind of changes in the app?

I was expecting to see a transaction on this change in the SKPaymentQueue or see indication for it when validating the receipt but I could not find anything when I changed from one subscription level to another (in the same subscription group).

Apple documentation on the storeKit (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6) mention cancellation but not subscription change.
How can the application (client side or server side) can be notified when a user changed his subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) on monthly periodically basis just before user plan going to renew, you can check in Product Identifier

> The product identifier of the item that was purchased.
>
> ASN.1 Field Type 1702
>
> ASN.1 Field Value UTF8STRING
>
> JSON Field Name product_id
>
> JSON Field Value string
>
> This value corresponds to the `productIdentifier` property of the
>   `SKPayment` object stored in the transaction’s payment property.

Comment: let me know if you want further assistance for validate receipts within the app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  The productIdentifier still appears as the original id and not the new one that the user switch to. I did not know that near the expiration date (I will need to wait a few more days for that) because I would like the changes to take affect soon in the app. Just to make sure - I am talking about switching product ids that are within the same product group. If they are on different groups, what you are suggesting will work.

Comment: Either subscription is within same group or from different group it will always have unique product_id so you can identify them. Moreover sandbox testing does not go well. And you need to save expiration date of each subscribed user in your server DB and update that according to receipt as user can skip/cancel and renew again subscription any time. In our app we have also setup all this procedure.

Comment: That is exactly what I did but seems like the real apple id I used already made that purchase so things got messed up. I tried it again with a clean and real apple id and it worked like a charm. I could see in latest_receipt_info 2 items: one for the original in app purchase id and one for the new. Thanks again!

Comment: We're currently having the same issue :)  By your last comment you mean that in the `latest_receipt_info` you receive a JSON array with both the previous and the current identifier for the purchased plans? Thank you in advance!